# Using Each in For Loop

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, foreach

I'm trying to use the Each keyword in For loop to enter the values in an array, but I couldn't do it in the below code, could you help me understanding the error in below code.

```vb
Dim Arr(4)

For Each Element in Arr

    Element = InputBox("Enter Data")

Next

'Nothing is getting stored in the Array: Arr()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't set an array element using the indexer returned from For Each (*), so you'll have to do something like this instead:

```
Dim Arr(4)

For i = 0 to 4
    Arr(i) = InputBox("Enter Data")
Next

For Each Element in Arr
    MsgBox Element
Next
```

(*) I would guess that it's a copy of the actual value

Answer (score 0):

For each loop only works for a pre-existing array data. It cannot be used for assignments.

If in case, you need to use for each loop, you can use the following method:

```
Dim Arr(4)

i=0

For Each Element in Arr
   Arr(i)= InputBox("Enter Data")
   i++

Next
```

I am actually not aware of the syntax, but the following concept will help you in feeding the data in the array.